# Can “standalone” ever be an adverb?

Tags: word-usage, adverbs, parts-of-speech, grammatical-roles

Is it correct to use word *standalone* as an adverb?

All the major dictionaries only mention that it is an adjective. However, I’ve seen many sources use it as an adverb. For example:

> This program can be run standalone.

Does this usage make sense? If not, then what’s the adverbial form corresponding to *standalone*?

Comment: The is an ellipsis there, though. This program can be run [as a] standalone [program].

Comment: Practically any adjective can be used as an adverb. _Do you want to do it standalone or with a helper?_ As long as it makes sense.

Comment: @JohnLawler is the first part of that about US English?

Comment: @JohnLawler When a program runs unseen and unencumbered, or a person lives happy and free, are those all really adverbs describing the verb not adjectives describing the subject?

Comment: You can look at it either way. The distinction is an artificial one in the first place, and it's becoming less and less useful in practice, as English becomes more analytic. POS are like phonemes; some analytic systems do better with more, others with fewer.

Comment: I think the fact that it's referring to "this program" qualifies it as an adjective functioning as a predicative adjunct: predicative because it relates to a predicand, here "this program", and an adjunct because it's a modifier in clause structure, i.e. in the VP.

Comment: ... whereas these programs must be run together.

Comment: It's not being used as an adverb. It's describing the subject NP and is, for that reason, an adjective. It is the equivalent of *frozen* in "This pizza can be served frozen", where "frozen" is a depictive Adjunct describing the Subject NP. Notice that you cannot say: *"This pizza can be served frozenly"

Comment: *Standalone* functions as an adverb here. Take your sentence out of the passive voice to see: *You can run this program standalone.* Also compare: *You can run this program fast* (where *fast* is a flat adverb).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139824/discussion-on-question-by-danny-can-standalone-ever-be-an-adverb).